# Getting an AWK command to work in Python script

Tags: python, awk

I have this command in my Python script -

```
client.connect(host, username=username, pkey=mykey)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('sudo grep -i "key_prefix" /path/to/my/file.txt | awk -F "'" '{ print $4}'')
```

However, I get the following error - 
`SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

How could I get the python script to cut up the string correctly?

This is the string I am performing the awk on -

`$conf['key_prefix'] = 'my_string';`.  The value that I want is the my_string value.  Inside of the bash console, it works correctly, but the python script throws an error.

If I add then all into a list, the value at index 0 of the list is this -

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
$conf['key_prefix'] = 'my_string';
$conf['key_prefix'] = 'my_string';
```

Any ideas to get the awk command to work?  Seems to be the easiest solution to the issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fairly certain you want to use some triple quotes here.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('sudo grep -i "key_prefix" /path/to/my/file.txt | awk -F "'" '{ print $4}'')
```

should become

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("""sudo grep -i "key_prefix" /path/to/my/file.txt | awk -F "'" '{ print $4}'""")
```

The problem (based off what I can see) is that your first `'` is matched right after the `-F"` and then you have a `"` after it which starts a new string.  Could be wrong but try triple quotes and see if that helps.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: Have to wait three more minutes.  I'll be sure to do that once the timer expires.